# .htaccess Folder Browsing

Tags: .htaccess

I have a "site" setup to allow myself some "public" downloads.
So in the root folder of the site I have an htaccess file containing

```
Options +Indexes 
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
```

Inside the site I have a couple folders with files for downloading, etc...

How can I disable the ability to get into the parent folder once inside one of these folders?

For instance...
http://o7thwd.com/dl/Mine

I'd like to prevent the `Parent Directory` from showing and being able to do anything...

Comment: What is the effect of removing the two lines from .htaccess? Are you still shown the Indexes or Forbidden? If you are forbidden, remove .htaccess from the site root folder and copy it to every subfolder that needs to be public.

Comment: That works.  Post this as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .htaccess file from the site's root folder.

Put the following (same as in your question) in .htaccess file in every sub-folder that needs to be public:

```
Options +Indexes 
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
```